# AES Шифрование в Delphi и Python

Tags: python, delphi, шифрование, aes

Есть 2 проекта. Веб проект, сделанный на Python(Flask) и десктоп приложение, для людей, у которых нету доступа к сети, написанное на Delphi XE 5.
Приложение на Delphi в свою очередь умеет выгружать результаты работы с программой в файл в формате Json. Файл необходимо шифровать методом AES для последующей передачи его в веб приложение, в котором оно дешифруется и загрузится в БД.

Вопрос №1: Существуют различные онлайн сервисы шифрования данных, я даже ссылки приводить не буду - их миллион. Меня сильно удивляет то, что каждый из них, даёт мне разные результаты(шифрованый текст выглядит по разному), хотя передаётся всем один и тот-же текст и пароль. Почему?(везде используется 256 битный ключ и один и тот-же метод шифрования)

Вопрос №2: Обратился я к онлайн сервисам от того, что не могу расшифровать на Python файл, который зашифровал в Delphi, и наоборот. Хотя каждый сам может расшифровать то, что зашифровал.

Выскажите свои предположения ...

Comment: Смотря что вы используете для шифрования в Delphi. По моим наблюдениям - самое правильное, что можно использовать, что легко стыкуется с реализациями на Java, ObjectiveC и RoR - это штатный виндовый API. DCPCrypt (самый легкий в использовании) стыковаться, увы, не захотел.

Comment: @kami DCPCrypt потому что коряв и крив, реализация чуть ли не половины методов в нем далека от стандарта.

Comment: Говорят ли вам что-то слова: вектор  инициализации (IV—почему каждый файл свой должен иметь и почему один и тот же текст может выглядеть по разному зашифрованный),  CFB, CTR режимы? Покажите как вы шифруете/расшифровываете [типа подобного кода](https://codeghar.wordpress.com/2013/09/06/beginning-aes-with-python3/). Помимо параметров шифрования, может ошибка при чтении данных с диска или при передачи по сети. Попробуйте небольшую строку зашифровать с заданным ключём и добавьте в вопрос (как base64).

Comment: Кроме того, насколько я знаю, при генерации ключа из пароля используется хэш-функция, которая у разных сервисов тоже может использоваться разная.

Answer (score 3):

Разные результаты шифрования у разных сервисов возникают по понятной причине различия в реализациях. Есть стандарт шифрования ([PDF-документ](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf)), но вот при его реализации могут быть опущены или сделаны по-своему какие-то части алгоритма. Вот [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/212235/) на Хабре про реализацию [AES-128 на Phyton](https://github.com/Skycker/AES) в качестве примера. Если прочесть статью, то в её заключении автор прямо говорит, что есть нюанс с шифрованием "хвоста" блока, если он меньше 16 байт и рассказывает про то, как поступил он. Другой автор реализации того же алгоритма вполне может поступить иначе и обработать "хвост" как-то иначе, и в итоге мы получим то, что казалось бы, 2 реализации одного и того же алгоритма "подружить" не получится. И это - только один из примеров подобных различий и вероятной причины вами описанной проблемы.

С другой стороны, меня несколько смущает тот факт, что вы сами говорите, что есть

> десктоп приложение, для людей, у которых нету доступа к сети.

Так почему же вы пытаетесь работать с онлайн-сервисами, если у десктопного клиента всё равно нет доступа к сети?

В вашей ситуации, как мне кажется, решением было бы использовать одну и ту же реализацию и для веб-приложения, и для десктопа.

Как именно это будет сделано - вопрос иной. И первое, что приходит в голову, это реализация через DLL, которая будет задействована и там, и там (если это технически возможно прикрутить DLL к вашему веб-приложению и дергать из неё функции шифрования).

Либо же берем готовую реализацию алгоритма шифрования на каком-то из обозначенных вами языков (да хоть тот же пример на Питоне по ссылке выше) и скрупулёзно, методично переписываем её на другой язык (на Делфи). Да и то, мне кажется, что вот так с ходу, гарантии полной совместимости не будет, например, по причине различий в реализации типов или особенностях работы с памятью.

Третьим вариантом может быть использование другого, более "дружелюбного" алгоритма, или использование собственного механизма шифрования, который знаете только вы). Либо вообще применение иного способа работы с данными (`[irony on]`передача данных в запароленном архиве 7z`[irony off]`).

Comment: Даже одна и та же реализация может для одного и того же текста и ключа разные результаты вернуть [из-за разных векторов инициализации, режимов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588726/aes-%d0%a8%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-delphi-%d0%b8-python#comment789583_588726)

Comment: А чем способ "передача данных в запароленном архиве 7z" плох и вы его не советуете? Почему ирония?

Comment: @VladChapl, он не то, что бы плох, просто скорее дело в том, что это "старый дедовский метод", который был актуален в 90-2000-е, а сейчас просто морально устарел. Особенно, если учесть что сейчас для безопасной передачи данных есть куча стандартов, алгоритмов, способов. Пусть меня гуру закидают тапками, но взломать запароленный архив 7z с сложным длинным паролем не видится мне такой уж вот простой задачей. Проще перехватить пароль для его паковки/распаковки. Но это уже другой вопрос.